# Firefox Keeps Crashing usually with Flash / Youtube

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash

This problem has been raised before can someone from the Ubuntu team please help? Or suggest alternative browser since Chrome does the same.

Thanks - Dev

Comment: it seems that your problem belongs to flash , not to your browser. so better try to check flash. what flashplugin do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with above. Its also affecting Chrome, Safari & even Opera. Roll your flash plugin back to an earlier version.